# PostgreSQL, SELECT from max id

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

By using libpq on PG 9.1, I am trying to write query to get values from row with highest index 'my_id':

```
SELECT my_id, col2, col3 
FROM mytable 
WHERE my_id = MAX(my_id)
```

That gives me error:

> ERROR: aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause...

How to write such query properly?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If your goal is to get the row with the highest my_id value, then the following query should achieve the same goal.

```
SELECT my_id, col2, col3 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY my_id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That's it, thanks. I can accept only one (fastest) but all answers helped, sorry.

Comment: One of those answers that seems obvious in retrospect.

Answer (score 13):

Just order by `my_id` and take only the first record with `limit 1`

```
SELECT my_id, col2, col3
FROM mytable 
order by my_id desc
limit 1
```

Another but less performant way would be

```
SELECT my_id, col2, col3
FROM mytable 
where my_id = (select max(my_id) from mytable)
```

Answer (score 8):

Sub query may help you

```
SELECT my_id, col2, col3 FROM mytable WHERE my_id = (select MAX(my_id) FROM mytable)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT my_id, col2, col3 FROM mytable WHERE my_id = (select MAX(my_id) FROM mytab)
```

or use

```
SELECT my_id, col2, col3 FROM mytable ORDER BY my_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

when you have an index on my_id the ones with the subquery should be faster. when you dont have an index take the "order by". (obv. depends on database size if relevant)

Comment: Probably the other way around. Postgres optimizes `LIMIT 1` queries where an index is applicable.